# What is the difference between "sourceCompatibility" and "targetCompatibility"?

Tags: gradle, java

What is the relationship/difference between `sourceCompatibility` and `targetCompatibility`? What happens when they are set to different values?

According to the [Toolchain and compatibility](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#toolchain_and_compatibility) section of the [Java plugin](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/java_plugin.html) Gradle documentation:

- `sourceCompatibility` is "Java version compatibility to use when compiling Java source."
- `targetCompatibility` is "Java version to generate classes for."

My understanding is that `targetCompatibility` will generate Java bytecode that is compatible with a specific version of Java. Is this a subset of the functionality of `sourceCompatibility`?

Answer (score 131, accepted):

`targetCompatibility` and `sourceCompatibility` maps to `-target release` and `-source release` in javac. Source is basically the source language level and target is the level of the bytecode that is generated.

More details can be found in the *Cross-Compilation Options for `javac`* section of *Tools Reference* [for Java 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html), [for Java 11](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/javac.html#GUID-AEEC9F07-CB49-4E96-8BC7-BCC2C7F725C9__CROSS-COMPILATIONOPTIONSFORJAVAC-7D3D83C3), [for Java 17](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/man/javac.html), [for Java 19](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/specs/man/javac.html) or [for Java 21](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/specs/man/javac.html).

Comment: The above link is pointing to doc for Java 7. I wonder if you want something like https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/javac.html#GUID-AEEC9F07-CB49-4E96-8BC7-BCC2C7F725C9 ?

Answer (score 97):

Be careful when you use these; we've been bitten by people making assumptions.

Just because you use sourceCompability (or targetCompatibility) of 1.5 doesn't mean you can always compile your code with JDK 1.6 and expect it to work under JDK 1.5. The issue is the available libraries.

If your code happens to call some method that is only available in JDK 1.6 it will still compile with the various Compatibility options for the target VM. But when you run it, it will fail because the offending method is not present (you'll get a MethodNotFoundException or ClassNotFoundException).

For this reason, I *always* compare the Compatibility setting to the actual Java version I'm building under. If they don't match, I fail the build.

Comment: This is a subtle, but very important observation.

Comment: How do you compare them?

Comment: Why do you fail the build? The "bootstrap classpath" option is given just for mitigating this issue. You can always use the proper bootstrap and it should work just fine.

Comment: `if(JavaVersion.current() != JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8) throw new GradleException("This project requires Java 8, but it's running on "+JavaVersion.current())` This is how I sort this issue out, right in the beginning of the build.gradle file.

Comment: Since Java 9 there is now a new `javac` option `--release` intended to address this problem, by only allowing use of API available in the specified Java version. For more on this see https://stackoverflow.com/a/43103038/4653517

Comment: @JamesMudd Wait, so before Java 9 we could use a method only available on Java 8 even though the compatibility was set to Java 1, for example, and the IDE wouldn't warn about that!?

Comment: Typically yes. When the IDE has a setting for language level it typically means the language constructs i.e. is a lambda valid etc. It does not know which methods were added to the standard libraries in which Java version. So it will just compile against the JVM in use by the IDE. If you want to ensure this use a JVM of the version you are targeting, and don't rely on these version options.

Answer (score 50):

**sourceCompatibility** =  specifies that version of the Java programming language be used to compile **.java** files.
e.g sourceCompatibility 1.6 =specifies that version 1.6 of the Java programming language be used to compile **.java** files.

*By default sourceCompatibility = "version of the current JVM in use" and targetCompatibility = sourceCompatibility*

**targetCompatibility** = The option ensures that the generated class files will be compatible with VMs specified by targetCompatibility . Note that in most cases, the value of the -target option is the value of the -source option; in that case, you can omit the -target option.

*Class files will run on the target specified by targetCompatibility and on later versions, but not on earlier versions of the VM*

Comment: how do we figure out which ones our project is using ?

Answer (score 3):

There have been given a lot of good explanations of what `sourceCompatibility` vs `targetCompatibility` is good for and a further good article can be found here [Gradle: sourceCompatiblity vs targetCompatibility](https://www.baeldung.com/gradle-sourcecompatiblity-vs-targetcompatibility). But instead of `sourceCompatibility` vs `targetCompatibility` I would suggest to use the Gradle `toolchain` (see [Toolchains for JVM projects](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/toolchains.html)) which makes `release` or `sourceCompatibility` tweaks obsolete and gurantees that langauge-features (`sourceCompatibility`), bytecode (`targetCompatibility`) and Java-API/-Libraries (`release`) will match the Java Version. (Only drawback is that the IDE support is not yet fully established but is on its way).

Comment: A reference on "toolchains making `release` or `sourceCompatibility` tweaks obselete": https://blog.gradle.org/java-toolchains. It took me some time to find this.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, “sourceCompatibility” means the what feature you can use in your source code.For example,if you set sourceCompatibility to 1.7, then you can't use lambda expression which a new feature in java 8 even though you jdk version is 1.8.
As for “targetCompatibility”, it means which version of jre the generated class file can be run on, if you set it to 1.8,it may not run successfully on jdk 1.7, but it can usually run on higher version of jdk.

Comment: This really explain what to be related with development in detail.

Answer (score 0):

These are the flags for the javac command.

```
javac [options] [sourcefiles]

Options:
...
-source release - Specifies the version of source code accepted.
...
-target release - Generates class files for a specific VM version.
...
```

In other words:  you write a code in a `source` version and compile your classes to the `target` VM version. In order to run it e.g. on other workstation with older java version.

According to: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/javac.html