# How do I specify the required Java version in a Gradle build?

Tags: java, gradle

I would like to set the required Java version (e.g. 7 or 8) in my Gradle build file *without* having to specify the actual path to a local JDK installation.

Is this possible?

Comment: You're looking for the equivalent of maven's enforcer plugin for jvm version, right? https://github.com/kordamp/enforcer-gradle-plugin/

Answer (score 40):

This feature was [just added](https://blog.gradle.org/java-toolchains) to Gradle 6.7 as [Java toolchains](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/toolchains.html):

```kotlin
// build.gradle.kts

plugins {
    id("java-library") // or id("application")
}

java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion.set(JavaLanguageVersion.of(11))
    }
}
```

With this in place Gradle will automatically download & use the appropriate JDK (using AdoptOpenJDK by default) for the specified Java version.

Comment: Do you know how to select a specific revision of the JDK, for example Java 8 revision 261? I cannot find the documentation of JavaLanguageVersion. :-(

Comment: Nevermind. I found https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/jvm/toolchain/JavaLanguageVersion.html. Seems like it's not possible at the moment. But the underlying infrastructure of Gradle seems to be prepared for fetching a specific revision.I get the following exception: "Unable to download toolchain. This might indicate that the combination (version, architecture, release/early access, ...) for the requested JDK is not available."

Answer (score 23):

TLDR;
Thanks @franklin-yu "targetCompatibility = '1.7' -> your user can compile with 8 and run with 7."

See [Gradle, "sourceCompatibility" vs "targetCompatibility"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16654951/gradle-sourcecompatibility-vs-targetcompatibility)

`targetCompatibility = '1.7'` does the trick for e.g. Java 7

Use `sourceCompatibility = '1.7'` for the language level

Comment: Also, if `targetCompatibility` is not specified, it defaults to `sourceCompatibility`.

Comment: No, these options set the target source code and byte-code compatibility. I need instead to specify what JDK version to use to carry out the compilation.

Comment: Gradle uses the JDK which it finds in your PATH, to select a different one set JAVA_HOME to the desired path

Comment: you can cross compile for an older JVM just by setting the targetCompatibility. you dont need the a specific JDK version. This naturally only works for older language versions.

Comment: In my build I've specified both `targetCompatibility` and `sourceCompatibility` however when a user download and compile the project with JDK 8 but, for any reason, run with Java 7, it will result in the following exception:
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.util.function.BiFunction
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_67]

Comment: `BiFunction` is a new addition to the Java 8 JDK. If your project depends on that class it cannot be run on a < Java 8 JRE.

Comment: No, I'm not using the `BiFunction` interface, but I guess it is referenced from some library when my project is compiled with Java 8. This why I was asking a way to stick the Java runtime version in the Gradle build

Comment: @Paulecci, if you have `targetCompatibility = '1.7'` in your `build.gradle`, your user can compile with 8 and run with 7.

Comment: @pditommaso ... Yes I have the same problem.  Build and compile target 1.7. When I run or debug from Gradle, it will use the local 1.8 `JAVA_HOME` runtime.  That seems OK but, the debugger _correctly_ loads 1.7 SDK sources and they are NOT the same as the 1.8 JDK executiing. _grrr_

Answer (score 13):

You can try this:

```
java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

tasks.withType<JavaCompile> {
    options.compilerArgs.addAll(arrayOf("--release", "8"))
}
```

This will also give JDK compliance to you. You can also see the following related issues:

- Gradle: [[Java 9] Add convenience method for `-release` compiler argument](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/2510)
- Eclipse Plug-ins for Gradle: [JDK API compatibility should match the sourceCompatibility option](https://github.com/eclipse/buildship/issues/934).

Answer (score 6):

In the `build.gradle` file, add the following two lines:

```
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
targetCompatibility = '1.8'
```

The `targetCompatibility` defines the generated JVM bytecode version (this is the version that users of your application need). The `sourceCompatibility` defines which source code constructs are allowed (e.g. you need Java 1.8 or higher to use lambda expressions in source code).

[Source](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#other_convention_properties)

Answer (score 3):

Based on the answer of CletusW.  In windows 10, it seems that the new installed Java will not be chosen automatically, so I check it manually.

```
apply plugin: 'java'
java.toolchain.languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(15)  // auto install



// check JDK version
if (!System.getProperty("java.home").contains(java.toolchain.languageVersion.get().toString())) {
    def msg = ('JDK in this project: ' + System.getProperty('java.home') + '\n' +
            'In this project, you should use JDK-' + java.toolchain.languageVersion.get())
    throw new GradleException(msg)
}
```

Comment: I have Gradle 7.2, the auto-download just starts.  Which I didn't like because I want to check the Java in-use or to use an existing installed version.