# How to open a project made with gradle 2.7 in intellij?

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, intellij-14

I need to open a gradle project, but IntelliJ doesn't support gradle versions below 3 (this one is in 2.7). I tried clicking the upgrade gradle version and reimport project link in the console, but that didn't work. I then tried to switch the boot JDK to java 8, but it says i can't go below 11. I have seen other people post in having the same problem in the same project, so I'm confident that switching the boot JDK will work. How do I do that?

Comment: WHat the reason to use such an old Gradle version? What is the project in question? What do you need to change? 1) Gradle JDK (https://i.imgur.com/IQyc2As.png) 2) Project JDK (can be set via [build.gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58646709/8203759), or in project's settings)

Comment: This is likely not a problem worth solving. Just upgrade to a newer Gradle.