# Downgrading Java Version

Tags: java, downgrade, java-19

I am trying to publish a React App to the Google Play Store, and I had downloaded and installed java 19, only to find out that the build command I need to run to publish the app is incompatible with version 19. I want to make sure I do this properly, so how do I go about downgrading to 18 without messing anything up

Comment: What's your build environment? If you're on a Debian-based system, [`alternatives`](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/alternatives-command) would be a pretty easy solution.

Comment: In all honesty I'm not particularly sure. I am using React Native and I believe that uses JDK

Comment: Don't have much knowledge of React Native, but I suppose it uses Gradle as build system, so you find help in the answers of [this qustion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27861658/2846138). Don't forget to set source and target compatibility to the version you want, compiling new features (of Java) to an older JVM is not very likely to work.