How can I fix "unsupported class file major version 65" in IntelliJ IDEA?
I have a Spring Boot project, it's written in Java 21 with Gradle 8.4. I have the Java 21 JDK installed. When I run it in IntelliJ IDEA, it throws an error:
2024-04-26 02:16:43.098 ERROR 904 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: file [C:\Users\tigra\Desktop\Java\blog\build\classes\java\main\ru\pet\blog\Blog.class]; nested exception is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: ASM ClassReader failed to parse class file - probably due to a new Java class file version that isn't supported yet: file [C:\Users\tigra\Desktop\Java\blog\build\classes\java\main\ru\pet\blog\Blog.class]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 65
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.scanCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:457) ~[spring-context-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:316) ~[spring-context-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.doScan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:276) ~[spring-context-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanAnnotationParser.parse(ComponentScanAnnotationParser.java:128) ~[spring-context-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:295) ~[spring-context-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:249) ~[spring-context-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:206) ~[spring-context-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:174) ~[spring-context-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:247) ~[spring-context-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:311) ~[spring-context-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:112) ~[spring-context-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:746) ~[spring-context-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:564) ~[spring-context-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:731) ~[spring-boot-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) ~[spring-boot-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303) ~[spring-boot-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292) ~[spring-boot-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8]
    at ru.pet.blog.Blog.main(Blog.java:10) ~[main/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: ASM ClassReader failed to parse class file - probably due to a new Java class file version that isn't supported yet: file [C:\Users\tigra\Desktop\Java\blog\build\classes\java\main\ru\pet\blog\Blog.class]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 65
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.getClassReader(SimpleMetadataReader.java:60) ~[spring-core-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:48) ~[spring-core-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:103) ~[spring-core-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:123) ~[spring-core-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.scanCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:429) ~[spring-context-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 65
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:199) ~[spring-core-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:180) ~[spring-core-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:166) ~[spring-core-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:287) ~[spring-core-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.getClassReader(SimpleMetadataReader.java:57) ~[spring-core-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    ... 23 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1

Everywhere they advise to update jdk or Gradle version, but I already did it :(
Here is my build.gradle:
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.2.5'
    id "io.spring.dependency-management" version "1.1.4"
    id 'java'
}


version = '1.0.2'
group = 'org.gradle.samples'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_21
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation platform('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:3.2.5')

    implementation ('org.casbin:jcasbin:1.55.0') {
        exclude module: "logback-classic"
    }
    implementation ('org.casbin:redis-adapter:1.0.0') {
        exclude module: "logback-classic"
    }

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:3.2.5'
    implementation 'io.github.lognet:grpc-spring-boot-starter:5.1.5'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.10.1'
    implementation 'org.flywaydb:flyway-core'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter:4.1.2'
    implementation 'org.grpcmock:grpcmock-spring-boot:0.11.0'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'

    runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'

    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher'
}


//dependencyManagement {
//    imports {
//        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
//    }
//}

tasks.named('test', Test) {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

I also tried migrating the project to Java 17 or using this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/64863465/287647
Did not help :(
What's going on here and how can I fix it?

Recompile ru.pet.blog.Blog with a supported JDK. Be sure you do a "clean build". That class was compiled with an unsupported JDK. If you don't have the source code to ru.pet.blog.Blog, contact the person that does.

It worked, thanks! But now I have another problem - SLF4J(W): Class path contains multiple SLF4J providers. Have you encountered anything like this?

https://stackoverflow.com/q/14024756/2970947

The exception indicates you have a version of Spring Boot (or at least a Spring/Spring Boot dependency), which doesn't support Java 21 (class file version 65). The error is thrown by ASM (a bytecode manipulation library) shaded as org.springframework.asm.ClassReader. As far as I'm aware, Spring Boot 3.2.5 should work fine on Java 21, which suggests that one of your other libraries is pulling in an incompatible older version.

It seems that this is a Java compilation error. Try recompiling the class with your current Java version or dropping to the java version that was used to compile the code in the first instance.
