# Is it possible to run kotlin grade plugin using jdk 7

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, kotlin

My project uses jdk 7 for compatibility reasons.

bottom portion of `build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.0'
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

When I use jdk 7 for gradle, I get this:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/jetbrains/kotlin/gradle/KotlinGradleModel : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.serialization.DefaultPayloadClassLoaderRegistry$2.resolveClass(DefaultPayloadClassLoaderRegistry.java:91)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.serialization.WellKnownClassLoaderRegistry$2.resolveClass(WellKnownClassLoaderRegistry.java:91)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.serialization.PayloadSerializerObjectInputStream.readClass(PayloadSerializerObjectInputStream.java:66)
  ... cut
```

If I switch to jdk 8 for running grade while project jdk is still jdk7, the build succeed. Is this expected behaviour?

Comment: If the plugin was compiled for Java8, then this is expected.  (I'm curious - what aspect of your build system *requires* Java7?)

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth old code base

Comment: But a Java8 JDK ought to be compatible with a Java7 codebase.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth should be, but then I wouldn't catch my code calling java 8 libs accidentally.

Comment: You can ask Gradle to set the [compilation target to Java 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16654951/gradle-sourcecompatibility-vs-targetcompatibility).

Comment: `You can ask Gradle to set the compilation target to Java 7` Yes, but it won't make `SecureRandom.getInstanceStrong()` compile error.

Comment: In addition to what @OliverCharlesworth suggested: Kotlin compiles the bytecode for the JVM 6 target by default. You can [point the Kotlin compiler to the JDK 7](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html#attributes-specific-for-jvm) with the `jdkHome` option.

Comment: It causes a compilation error for me :/

Comment: `It causes a compilation error for me :/` interesting. I will try it tonight.

Comment: I've just tried it myself and it compiles, incorrectly. `SecureRandom.getInstanceStrong()`. I think it was explained by answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/22326989/887290

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After hours of research, I finally found this post:

https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2017/04/kotlin-1-1-2-is-out/

> The Kotlin compiler now requires JDK 8 to run. You shouldn’t notice
>   any changes, because most other Java development tools such as Gradle
>   and the Android toolchain also require JDK 8, so you almost certainly
>   already have it installed. For code generated by the compiler, Java
>   1.6 compatibility is still the default, and we have no plans to drop support for generating Java 1.6 compatible bytecode.

So, the answer is no.