# Move to OpenJDK-11 but compile in Java 8

Tags: java, gradle, java-8, java-11

I have an existing `Spring boot` App that i build through `gradle` . All these days I have been using `JDK / JRE 8` and now I am trying to use `JDK-11`

So to check the Compatability, I am setting the `JAVA_HOME` to `JDK-11` but trying to compile in `Java 8` mode

I added the below block in my `build.gradle`

```
compileJava {
    targetCompatibility = '1.8'
}
```

and then I set `JAVA_HOME` explicitly `set JAVA_HOME=C:\Users\arun\Desktop\jdk-11.0.1`

and then execute `gradlew clean build`

But I am stopped with the below exception

```
> Configure project :
Build Version = build-182-ga03cf6c

> Task :compileJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> warning: source release 11 requires target release 11
```

How to point my `JAVA_HOME` to `JDK-11` but still execute it in `Java-8` mode ?

Comment: They should ideally provide a `--release` equivalent parameter choice now as Maven does. `<release>`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'd say :

```
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
targetCompatibility = '1.8'
```

Because the default value of sourceCompatibility is the version of the current JVM in use.

source : https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html

Answer (score 5):

you need to set the sourceCompatibility too.

See this post here
[Gradle, "sourceCompatibility" vs "targetCompatibility"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16654951/gradle-sourcecompatibility-vs-targetcompatibility)

Answer (score 3):

As of Java 9 you can use the --release N option to cross-compile with Gradle. Setting the sourceCompatibility and targetCompatibility is not enough because in that case you need to set the bootClasspath to JDK N too. See [What is the --release flag in the Java 9 compiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43102787/what-is-the-release-flag-in-the-java-9-compiler) for more details.

Instead, use the Java 9+ "--release" compilerArg like this:

compilerArgs.addAll(['--release', '8'])

https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.CompileOptions.html