# How to build Beanshell with ANT?

Tags: ant, beanshell

I have a task: to build this project I have a project `git clone --depth 1 --branch 2.0b6 https://github.com/beanshell/beanshell.git`from sources whit JDK11 or report that sources are broken or report that they are incompatible with JDK 11. For that I have change `build.xml` to `<javac target="1.8"` then ran `ant`
And got the following error:

```
compile:
    [javac] /home/katya/tmp_work/beanshell/build.xml:176: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
    [javac] Compiling 48 source files to /home/katya/tmp_work/beanshell/classes
    [javac] 
    [javac]           WARNING
    [javac] 
    [javac] The -source switch defaults to 9 in JDK 9.
    [javac] If you specify -target 1.8 you now must also specify -source 1.8.
    [javac] Ant will implicitly add -source 1.8 for you.  Please change your build file.
    [javac] warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 8
    [javac] /home/katya/tmp_work/beanshell/src/bsh/util/AWTDemoApplet.java:30: warning: [deprecation] Applet in java.applet has been deprecated
    [javac] import java.applet.Applet;
    [javac]                   ^
    [javac] /home/katya/tmp_work/beanshell/src/bsh/util/AWTRemoteApplet.java:30: warning: [deprecation] Applet in java.applet has been deprecated
    [javac] import java.applet.Applet;
    [javac]                   ^
    [javac] /home/katya/tmp_work/beanshell/src/bsh/util/AWTConsole.java:122: warning: [deprecation] getModifiers() in InputEvent has been deprecated
    [javac]         type( e.getKeyCode(), e.getKeyChar(), e.getModifiers() );
    [javac]                                                ^
    [javac] /home/katya/tmp_work/beanshell/src/bsh/util/AWTConsole.java:146: warning: [deprecation] CTRL_MASK in InputEvent has been deprecated
    [javac]                 if ( (modifiers & InputEvent.CTRL_MASK) > 0 ) {
    [javac]                                             ^
    [javac] /home/katya/tmp_work/beanshell/src/bsh/util/AWTConsole.java:173: warning: [deprecation] CTRL_MASK in InputEvent has been deprecated
    [javac]                 if ( (modifiers & InputEvent.CTRL_MASK) > 0 ) {
    [javac]                                             ^
    [javac] /home/katya/tmp_work/beanshell/src/bsh/util/AWTConsole.java:217: warning: TextComponentPeer is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
    [javac]         ((java.awt.peer.TextComponentPeer)getPeer()).setCaretPosition( 
    [javac]                        ^
    [javac] /home/katya/tmp_work/beanshell/src/bsh/util/AWTConsole.java:217: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]         ((java.awt.peer.TextComponentPeer)getPeer()).setCaretPosition( 
    [javac]                                           ^
    [javac]   symbol:   method getPeer()
    [javac]   location: class AWTConsole
    [javac] /home/katya/tmp_work/beanshell/src/bsh/util/AWTDemoApplet.java:38: warning: [deprecation] Applet in java.applet has been deprecated
    [javac] public class AWTDemoApplet extends Applet
    [javac]                                    ^
    [javac] /home/katya/tmp_work/beanshell/src/bsh/util/AWTRemoteApplet.java:39: warning: [deprecation] Applet in java.applet has been deprecated
    [javac] public class AWTRemoteApplet extends Applet
    [javac]                                      ^
    [javac] /home/katya/tmp_work/beanshell/src/bsh/util/JConsole.java:227: warning: [deprecation] getModifiers() in InputEvent has been deprecated
    [javac]                 if ( (e.getModifiers() & InputEvent.CTRL_MASK) > 0 ) {
    [javac]                        ^
    [javac] /home/katya/tmp_work/beanshell/src/bsh/util/JConsole.java:227: warning: [deprecation] CTRL_MASK in InputEvent has been deprecated
    [javac]                 if ( (e.getModifiers() & InputEvent.CTRL_MASK) > 0 ) {
    [javac]                                                    ^
    [javac] /home/katya/tmp_work/beanshell/src/bsh/util/JConsole.java:263: warning: [deprecation] getModifiers() in InputEvent has been deprecated
    [javac]                     if (( (e.getModifiers() & InputEvent.CTRL_MASK) > 0 )
    [javac]                             ^
    [javac] /home/katya/tmp_work/beanshell/src/bsh/util/JConsole.java:263: warning: [deprecation] CTRL_MASK in InputEvent has been deprecated
    [javac]                     if (( (e.getModifiers() & InputEvent.CTRL_MASK) > 0 )
    [javac]                                                         ^
    [javac] /home/katya/tmp_work/beanshell/src/bsh/util/JConsole.java:281: warning: [deprecation] getModifiers() in InputEvent has been deprecated
    [javac]                     (e.getModifiers() & 
    [javac]                       ^
    [javac] /home/katya/tmp_work/beanshell/src/bsh/util/JConsole.java:282: warning: [deprecation] CTRL_MASK in InputEvent has been deprecated
    [javac]                     (InputEvent.CTRL_MASK 
    [javac]                                ^
    [javac] /home/katya/tmp_work/beanshell/src/bsh/util/JConsole.java:283: warning: [deprecation] ALT_MASK in InputEvent has been deprecated
    [javac]                     | InputEvent.ALT_MASK | InputEvent.META_MASK)) == 0 ) 
    [javac]                                 ^
    [javac] /home/katya/tmp_work/beanshell/src/bsh/util/JConsole.java:283: warning: [deprecation] META_MASK in InputEvent has been deprecated
    [javac]                     | InputEvent.ALT_MASK | InputEvent.META_MASK)) == 0 ) 
    [javac]                                                       ^
    [javac] /home/katya/tmp_work/beanshell/src/bsh/util/JDemoApplet.java:38: warning: [deprecation] JApplet in javax.swing has been deprecated
    [javac] public class JDemoApplet extends JApplet
    [javac]                                  ^
    [javac] /home/katya/tmp_work/beanshell/src/bsh/util/JRemoteApplet.java:39: warning: [deprecation] JApplet in javax.swing has been deprecated
    [javac] public class JRemoteApplet extends JApplet
    [javac]                                    ^
    [javac] /home/katya/tmp_work/beanshell/tests/src/InterfaceImpl.java:5: warning: [deprecation] Integer(int) in Integer has been deprecated
    [javac]     public Integer getInteger() { return new Integer(5); }
    [javac]                                          ^
    [javac] Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
    [javac] 1 error
    [javac] 20 warnings
```

in the same time it is impossible to build this project with Maven. Could you tell me how to build beanshell version 2.0b6 with JDK 11 ?

Comment: Humm - I'm not sure it will be possible with Java11. This thread outlines java 11 to java8, but not java 6. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54447541/how-to-produce-code-in-java-11-but-target-java-8-and-above

Comment: @emeraldjava I'm not sure that this post is related to mine.

Comment: it seems like this project require JDK 8 to build