# java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class lombok.javac.apt.LombokProcessor cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment

Tags: java, spring, maven, lombok, intellij-lombok-plugin

I am somewhat new to coding and am trying to use the Lombok plugin to automatically create Getters/Setters e.t.c. for my fields of a specific class. In doing so I get greeted with the following error:

The error:

> java: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class lombok.javac.apt.LombokProcessor (in unnamed module @0x3b67ef9b) cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment (in module jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.processing to unnamed module @0x3b67ef9b

After doing some searching online, I found out that this error is related to an issue in OpenJDK 15 but I am currently using OpenJDK 16, hence why I am confused that I am still getting this error.

This thread claims to have a solution: https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/2681#issuecomment-748616687 but after implementing the plugin, it does not seem to make any difference and I still receive the error.

I have most likely made a trivial mistake since I am a beginner but if someone knows what I am missing please let me know.

#### Class Using @Data (Lombok):

```
import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class Ingredient {

    private final String id;
    private final String name;
    private final Type type;

    public enum Type {
        WRAP, PROTEIN, VEGGIES, CHEESE, SAUCE
    }

}
```

#### My Pom File:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>sia</groupId>
    <artifactId>taco-cloud</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>taco-cloud</name>
    <description>Taco Cloud Project</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>16</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: If you are on JDK16 why not using records? If you are a beginner why not using the fundamentals to learn how they work? Lombok is known not working correctly in the published version on JDK16... so you have to wait either a newer version is available or just use plain java ... (IDE can help here a lot...) ....

Comment: BTW: can you tell where you found that: `.. is related to an issue in OpenJDK 15`..?

Comment: @khmarbaise I thought that it was an issue with OpenJDK 15 since this post signified that in the release version of OpenJDK 16 the problem would no longer be present: https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/2681#issuecomment-749000759 but looking back, I think he was simply referring to a beta build of OpenJDK 16?

Comment: Yes JDK16 has closed things which had been left open before (internal things in the JDK) which are being used by Lombok etc. and it was clear for a longer time that the closing will happen....

Comment: @khmarbaise I see, thanks for the info. Is there a workaround to still use Lombok in JDK 16 or should I switch to JDK 15 or earlier?

Comment: @khmarbaise As a heads-up, I have opted to remove the Lombok dependency and instead made my Getters, Setters, e.t.c. manually in the code. Got my application to run successfully after that.

Comment: I was getting a similar error doing a maven clean install on mac with open jdk 13. I downgraded the java version to 11 and was able to build the project with no errors.


[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project phms-domain: Fatal error compiling: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class lombok.javac.apt.LombokProcessor (

Comment: In my simple maven project, I am not using lombok still I am getting above error. In IntelliJ I am using another separate Gradle project with lombok. Could that be the cause?

Answer (score 507, accepted):

Switch to at least the `1.18.22` version of Lombok that contains [the fix](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/2681)

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
  <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
  <version>1.18.28</version>
</dependency>
```

To see the last version of lombok, follow this link on [search.maven.org](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:org.projectlombok%20a:lombok)

Comment: I am still getting the error with this version (1.18.20) and Java 16. It disappears when I downgrade to Java 15.

Comment: In my case I've to update the spring boot version 2.4.2 > 2.5.1

Comment: Worked for me, I'm using Java 16

Comment: I have this problem on IntelliJ community  2021.2 version that do not have any spring boot initializer... How I can fix that?

Comment: This works for me in Java 17 .. thanks.

Comment: Woks under openjdk 11

Comment: Worked for me, openjdk version "11.0.13" 2021-10-19 LTS

Comment: Thanks.
It got fixed after upgrading lombok to 1.18.22 .  (on JDK 16)

Comment: I was using lombok-1.18.24.jar in Eclipse. In pom, existing version was 1.18.16. Updated to 1.18.24. Worked for me.

Comment: This worked for me. JAVA_HOME version is 18.0.1.1 (vscode java.jdt.ls.java.home=jdk-18.0.1.1), Java version of the Maven Project is jdk1.8.0_341.

Comment: In my case I downgraded java version from 17 to 11 and it worked fine!

Comment: In my case, I was facing this issue after upgrading AGP 7.4.2 and this fix resolved the error. Thank you

Answer (score 12):

It seems can be solved by adding plugin in `pom.xml`

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>16</source>
        <target>16</target>
        <!--                    <release>16</release>-->
        <fork>true</fork>
        <compilerArgs>
            <arg>--enable-preview</arg>
            <arg>-Xlint:all</arg>
            <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
            <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
            <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
            <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
            <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.model=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
            <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.parser=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
            <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
            <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
            <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
            <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.jvm=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
        </compilerArgs>
        <!--for unmappable characters in classes-->
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
        <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
        <!--for lombok annotations to resolve-->
        <!--contradictory to maven, intelliJ fails with this-->
        <annotationProcessorPaths>
            <path>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                <version>1.18.16</version>
            </path>
        </annotationProcessorPaths>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

solution from [Lombok's access to jdk.compiler's internal packages incompatible with Java-16](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65380359/lomboks-access-to-jdk-compilers-internal-packages-incompatible-with-java-16)

Comment: I have attempted to implement this, but receive the following error:
```java: invalid source release 15 with --enable-preview
  (preview language features are only supported for release 16)
```

I then attempted to use release 16 but then received the original error.

Answer (score 4):

**@[FrankyFred](https://stackoverflow.com/users/540380/frankyfred) has provided a temporary solution to be able to use Lombok: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66981165/12586904**

---

<strike>As far as my research goes and the various responses that I received to this question, it seems like **there is no possible way of running *Lombok* currently in *OpenJDK 16***. As such, **an alternative to using *Lombok* is to put the `@data` methods manually in your code. The following link briefly explains how to do this in case you are new to this topic: [https://javabydeveloper.com/lombok-data-annotation/#:~:text=Lombok%20Data%20annotation%20(%20%40Data%20),as%20well%20as%20a%20constructor.](https://javabydeveloper.com/lombok-data-annotation/#:%7E:text=Lombok%20Data%20annotation%20(%20%40Data%20),as%20well%20as%20a%20constructor.)**</strike>

Sample pseudo code representing what `@Data` really represents:

```
@Getter @Setter 
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@ToString 
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class User1 {
  private Long id;
  private String username;
  
}
```

The *Lombok* `@Data` annotation minimizes the usage of more annotations when you need to generate all the above seven requirements, but **they essentially achieve the same objectives when running the code.**

I am by no means an expert at this, but hopefully, this will help anyone else who gets stuck using *Lombok* but needs to find an alternative since their book/tutorial might utilize it and u would still like to continue with the book/tutorial.