# lombok.javac.apt.LombokProcessor can't access com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment due to module restrictions

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, lombok, intellij-lombok-plugin

I am facing this error while running command:
`mvn clean install -DskipTests`

The error:
`class lombok.javac.apt.LombokProcessor (in unnamed module @0x7e7740a5) cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment (in module jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.processing to unnamed module @0x7e7740a5`

I tried to resolve it by following steps mentioned here:
[java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class lombok.javac.apt.LombokProcessor cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66801256/java-lang-illegalaccesserror-class-lombok-javac-apt-lombokprocessor-cannot-acce?newreg=61114112959745edaa3e0ac9a83cd407)

But it didn't worked for me. Please let me know what I am missing

Comment: You probably still have a Lombok version in use that's too old, maybe due to some caching issue or dependency problem. Check what version you are really using.

Answer (score 1):

You should either:

- Update your Lombok version, to a version that doesn't try to access that class, which is no longer public.
- Lower the SDK version used by maven (you can look at it by running `mvn -v`), to 1.8 for example.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: looks like bumping the lombok version has fixed this issue for me. Had to change from `1.18.12` to `1.18.30`