# java build fails with gradle

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

I am very new to JAVA. I just cloned a `springboot microservice`.
I am trying to build it using `./gradlew clean build` Also I am using IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate.

I am getting the following error.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class lombok.javac.apt.LombokProcessor (in unnamed module @0x68f76bb8) cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment (in module jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.processing to unnamed module @0x68f76bb8
```

I am using `openjdk17` if that matters. I also seem to have managed to install `adoptopenjdk8`. How can i fix the above error?

> Also since I am using gradle, how do I know which version of Java was
> used to write the service?

Comment: which ide your are using now ? STS or eclipse or Intellij idea

Comment: @RajeshPatel IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate

Comment: you can check mvn version and set java path then you have to intall lombok tool then find lombok tool is compatible with open jdk 17 or not

Comment: @RajeshPatel man how to do all that, can you add it as steps in the answer?

Comment: Found a similar issue here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65380359/lomboks-access-to-jdk-compilers-internal-packages-incompatible-with-java-16

Answer (score 1):

from command line check maven version

```
mvn -v
```

install lombok plugin from intellij idea

got to file -> settings -> plugin then search lombok then install it.

you have to check also from gradle file is there lombok dependecy is available or not. if available then update with new version

set java path

```
Windows 10 and Windows 8
- In Search, search for and then select: System (Control Panel)
- Click the Advanced system settings link.
- Click Environment Variables. In the section System Variables find the PATH environment variable and select it. Click Edit. If the PATH environment variable does not exist, click New.
- In the Edit System Variable (or New System Variable) window, specify the value of the PATH environment variable. Click OK. Close all remaining windows by clicking OK.
- open cmd check javac command
```

Comment: I am on a mac...

Comment: https://mkyong.com/java/how-to-set-java_home-environment-variable-on-mac-os-x/