# error compiling[m: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class lombok.javac.apt.LombokProcessor

Tags: java, maven, avro, lombok, sts

I am facing below error while building code Spring Boot and Apache Avro example from STS, however if I run this code command line it works well.

```
[INFO] [1m--- [0;32mmaven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile[m [1m(default-compile)[m @ [36mavroposgen[0;1m ---[m
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 8 source files to E:\Kafka-Streams-with-Spring-Cloud\avroposgen\target\classes
[INFO] [1m------------------------------------------------------------------------[m
[INFO] [1;31mBUILD FAILURE[m
[INFO] [1m------------------------------------------------------------------------[m
[INFO] Total time:  5.729 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-12-15T22:00:20+05:30
[INFO] [1m------------------------------------------------------------------------[m
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal [32morg.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile[m [1m(default-compile)[m on project [36mavroposgen[m: [1;31mFatal error compiling[m: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class lombok.javac.apt.LombokProcessor (in unnamed module @0x18ff1520) cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment (in module jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.processing to unnamed module @0x18ff1520 -> [1m[Help 1][m
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the [1m-e[m switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the [1m-X[m switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [1m[Help 1][m http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>learningjournal.guru.examples</groupId>
    <artifactId>avroposgen</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Avro Pos Generator</name>
    <description>Avro Pos Generator by Learning Journal</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
            <artifactId>avro</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-avro-serializer</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
                <artifactId>avro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.8.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>schema</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceDirectory>src/main/avro</sourceDirectory>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources</outputDirectory>
                            <imports>
                                <import>${project.basedir}/src/main/avro/LineItem.avsc</import>
                                <import>${project.basedir}/src/main/avro/DeliveryAddress.avsc</import>
                            </imports>
                            <stringType>String</stringType>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>confluent</id>
            <url>https://packages.confluent.io/maven/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

[image]

Comment: I would verify your Eclipse settings are using the same JDK and Maven versions as your terminal

Comment: you omitted the most important parts of the output: the jdk & version info & parameters ... it looks like incorrect `JAVA_HOME`/version to me. [see also](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65380359/592355). (or the ´
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM´ in `SpringToolSuite4.ini`!? -> new answer!? )

Answer (score 0):

```
In eclipse go to->
Step 1 : window->preference->java->complier-> set compiler compliance level to 1.8 if you are using jdk1.8 or java8

Step 2:window->preference->java->installed JREs->
EDIT(if your installed JRE is not being used)->
JRE HOME : (the one which you have installed in your system jre path 
should be that of inside jdk)
in my case it is-> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291\jre

Please try to change these config of your ide.
Seems your compiler or jre version is not matched in ide as per installed 
java version.
```