# Why am I getting java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class lombok.javac.apt.LombokProcessor error?

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, build.gradle, lombok

I know there are other similar questions like this, but I have gone through all of them, and none worked for me, hence my asking it here.

I'm using gradle for my project, and when I build, it builds successfully, but when I try to compile using:

```
/gradlew app:compileJava
```

I get this error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:compileJava'.
> java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class lombok.javac.apt.LombokProcessor (in unnamed module ...) cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment (in module jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.processing to unnamed module ...
```

My dependency for lombok currently looks like this:

```
dependencies {
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testAnnotationProcessor  'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testCompileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'

...
}
```

I have also tried adding a specific version number to the dependences like for example:

```
annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.20'
```

And I was still getting same error.

I'm using jdk 15 (tried using 17, 16 and 11, same error).

When I check my annotation processor in intelliJ, I see there is a processor path with lombok version 1.18.16. I don't know if this might be the issue, but when I delete the cache in .gradle folder, after building, it pops up again. Here is a screenshot.

[image: annotation processor screenshot]

Please any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: What is the whole build.gradle? Do you have sourceCompatibility = '16'
and targetCompatibility = '16' there?

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/68323986/8203759

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I finially did, was to downgrade my java version to 8, but there are some packages that requires at least version 11 to function. So I added this in my build.gradle:

```
java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(11)
    }
}
```

Note: You should have both version 11 Nand 8 installed for this to work.