# Unable to bind values from JSON to Entity object in spring JPA

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a very simple application where I get `POST` request and save the JSON request to database.Here is my `Entity` object

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "PRODUCT_TBL")
@Entity
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private int quantity;
    private  double price;
}
```

Here is my controller

```
@RestController
public class ProductController {
    @Autowired
    ProductService productService;
    @PostMapping(value = "/save",consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public Product saveProduct(@RequestBody Product product){
        System.out.println(product);//check whether properties are binded properly
        return productService.saveProduct(product);
    }
}
```

Here is my sample post request

```
{
 
  "name":"moto",
  "quantity":5,
  "price":50.00
}
```

But whenever I am seeing the logs, they are binding to default values

> Product{name='null', quantity=0, price=0.0}

Comment: Show us the controller class with all annotations.

Comment: @Mar-Z added the complete controller class

Comment: It looks good. This should work with proper dependencies including Jackson JSON library.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced a similar issue in the past. In my case problem was with `lombok`. I forgot to add `annotationProcessor` dependency along with `lombok`. Make sure to add appropriate dependency of `lombok` and `annotationProcessor`.[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65380359/lomboks-access-to-jdk-compilers-internal-packages-incompatible-with-java-16) post might help you in adding right dependencies