# java.lang.IllegalAccessError with lombok 1.18.30 and java 21 and java 17

Tags: java, gradle, lombok, java-21

I'm getting the following error when trying to compile with gradle.

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class lombok.javac.apt.LombokProcessor (in unnamed module @0x44492a8a) cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment (in module jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.processing to unnamed module @0x44492a8a
```

I've seen several threads about people running into this issue with earlier versions of lombok, and the solution was simply to upgrade to the latest.  Well, I'm using the latest lombok and am still getting this error.  I've tried java 21 and java 17 with the same result--it only works with java 8. I've tried a few different versions of gradle, too, though only 8.5 is supposed to be compatible with java 21.

Any ideas how to fix it?

EDIT:

Relevant parts of my build.gradle config:

```
compileOnly('org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.30')
apply plugin: 'io.franzbecker.gradle-lombok'

import io.franzbecker.gradle.lombok.task.DelombokTask

task delombok(type: DelombokTask, dependsOn: compileJava) {
    ext.outputDir = file("$buildDir/delombok")
    outputs.dir(outputDir)
    sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs.each {
        inputs.dir(it)
        args(it, "-d", outputDir)
    }
    doFirst {
        outputDir.deleteDir()
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you invoke Lombok? Gradle, maven? Please add the respective config files to your question. When exactly does the error occur? More context around the error message could also help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lombok's access to jdk.compiler's internal packages incompatible with Java-16](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65380359/lomboks-access-to-jdk-compilers-internal-packages-incompatible-with-java-16)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the gradle plugin.  I'm replacing with another that will handle my lombok needs.

io.franzbecker.gradle-lombok

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Referring to [lombok changelog](https://projectlombok.org/changelog), version 1.18.30 should support JDK21.

> PLATFORM: Initial JDK21 support added. Issue #3393

To set the lombok version using the lombok plugin,
following the [documentation](https://github.com/franzbecker/gradle-lombok?tab=readme-ov-file#usage), you should set like

```
lombok {
    version("1.18.30")
}
```

And there should be no need to set something like
`compileOnly('org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.30')`
as it should be [added by the plugin](https://github.com/franzbecker/gradle-lombok?tab=readme-ov-file#motivation)